# Use string variable in static void

Tags: c#

I have a little problem with my code, I would like to use two variables string numberTextBox1 and numberTextBox2 in a static void function to replace the variables chiffre_1 and chiffre_2

I looked at converting string to var ==> failure
I tried to set the variables numberTextBox 1 and 2 ==> as a function argument
I tried to set function variables equal to TextBox1.Text and TextBox2.Text ==> failed

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using IronPython;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using System.IO;

namespace CSharp_with_Python_Script
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string nombreTextbox1;
        string nombreTextbox2;
        string chiffre_1;
        string chiffre_2;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        static void Execute(nombreTextBox1, 
 nombreTextBox2)
        {



            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.FileName = 
@"C:\Users\adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe";              



            var script = @"C:\Users\adm\Documents\Visual Studio 
2017\Projects\CSharp_with_Python_Script\Class_Plot\Class_Plot.py";     
            var chiffre_1 = nombreTextBox1;
            var chiffre_2 = nombreTextBox2;
            psi.Arguments = $"\"{script}\" \"{chiffre_1}\" \"{chiffre_2}\"";


            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardError = true;


            var errors = "";
            var result = "";

            using (var process = Process.Start(psi))
            {
                errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            }



        }

        private void Btn_ChangePicture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = (@"C:\Users\adm\Documents\Visual 
Studio 
2017\Projects\CSharp_with_Python_Script\Class_Plot\PLOT_MATPLOTLIB.png");
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
        }


        private void Btn_Script_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
            Execute();
        } 

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            nombreTextbox1 = textBox1.Text;
            nombreTextbox2 = textBox2.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like the variables chiffre_1 and chiffre_2 of the function to be equal to the variables entered in the function Execute

Ps: I am a beginner in C # and novice in the functions

Comment: so ? who has a idea ?

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using IronPython;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using System.IO;

namespace CSharp_with_Python_Script
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string nombreTextbox1;
        string nombreTextbox2;
        string chiffre_1;
        string chiffre_2;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        static void Execute()
        {

            chiffre_1 = nombreTextBox1;
            chiffre_2 = nombreTextBox2;

            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.FileName = 
@"C:\Users\adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe";              



            var script = @"C:\Users\adm\Documents\Visual Studio 
2017\Projects\CSharp_with_Python_Script\Class_Plot\Class_Plot.py";     
            var chiffre_1 = nombreTextBox1;
            var chiffre_2 = nombreTextBox2;
            psi.Arguments = $"\"{script}\" \"{chiffre_1}\" \"{chiffre_2}\"";


            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardError = true;


            var errors = "";
            var result = "";

            using (var process = Process.Start(psi))
            {
                errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            }



        }

        private void Btn_ChangePicture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = (@"C:\Users\adm\Documents\Visual 
Studio 
2017\Projects\CSharp_with_Python_Script\Class_Plot\PLOT_MATPLOTLIB.png");
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
        }


        private void Btn_Script_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
            Execute();
        } 

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            nombreTextbox1 = textBox1.Text;
            nombreTextbox2 = textBox2.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

When throw event `button1_Click` it's set `nombreTextbox1` and `nombreTextbox2` after that `Btn_Script_Click` launch `Execute()` method and use a private property to set `chiffre_1` and `chiffre_2` with a new value.

Comment: thanks for your answer, in the function execute, the textBox1 are underlined in red and it does not make the change as requested

Comment: textBox1 exists in Form1 interface designer?
If yes remove static from Execute method